# Register push notification Swift 3 + iOS 10

Tags: apple-push-notifications, swift3, ios10, xcode8, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to implement rich push notification but having issue with register push notification.

Anybody help me?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Here is a detailed guide: https://eladnava.com/send-push-notifications-to-ios-devices-using-xcode-8-and-swift-3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the apple doc and found the one way, some `Class` is depericated in iOS 10 which we using till iOS 9.x

Steps are there:

1. Add framework `UserNotifications`
2. Add one keys in info plist (I did because i'm using background fetch), check screenshot
3. Use below code and send the token to your server

### To register remote notification

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in

        // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
        if granted == true
        {
            print("Allow")
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
        else
        {
            print("Don't Allow")
        }
    }
```

### Get Token

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print(deviceToken)
}
```

[image]